# docker-compose and powershell - copy files into 'C:\Program Files' within Windows container

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I have Docker **Windows** container and need to copy some files **within** the container in my Powershell script.

In container, I have successfully mounted directory with files I need to copy under "C:\tmp\dotnetpacakges\". Once the container is up, I need to copy the contents to "C:\Program Files\...\".

I'm trying to achieve this using:

`docker-compose exec myservice powershell cp C:\tmp\dotnepackages\ "C:\Program Files\path"`

The command above works fine as long as there is no space in path. My path contains a space and I just can't get it to work. I have tried:

- double quotes: "C:\Program Files\path"
- double quotes escaping with `: "`"C:\Program Files\path`""
- single quotes escaping with `: '`"C:\Program Files\path`"'
- mix of single and double quotes: '"C:\Program Files\path"'

How should I pass the file path with space so that it will be recognized as one argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it should be **double quotes with escaped single quotes**.

Like: 
`` "`'C:\Program Files\path`'" ``